# Dropping NA values of factors within a function

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

### Toy data:

Say I have this df

```
df <- structure(list(x = structure(c(NA, 7L, NA, NA, 4L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 
3L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, NA), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor"), y = structure(c(NA, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, NA, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), z = structure(c(NA, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, NA, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, NA), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
    a = c(-32L, -51L, -22L, 44L, 55L, -24L, -50L, 67L, 1L, -47L, 
    66L, -98L, -91L, -42L, -89L, -31L, -8L, -33L, 38L, 61L), 
    b = c(46L, -19L, -37L, 47L, -28L, -48L, 14L, -10L, -13L, 
    -31L, 32L, 21L, -21L, 25L, -8L, 42L, -26L, -24L, 36L, -39L
    )), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

df

# A tibble: 20 × 5
   x     y     z         a     b
   <fct> <fct> <fct> <int> <int>
 1 NA    NA    NA      -32    46
 2 7     2     4       -51   -19
 3 NA    3     4       -22   -37
 4 NA    2     4        44    47
 5 4     2     5        55   -28
 6 6     2     4       -24   -48
 7 6     2     5       -50    14
 8 2     1     5        67   -10
 9 3     3     2         1   -13
10 5     NA    NA      -47   -31
11 8     2     4        66    32
12 4     3     1       -98    21
13 7     1     1       -91   -21
14 3     1     3       -42    25
15 5     3     2       -89    -8
16 1     2     5       -31    42
17 5     2     2        -8   -26
18 5     3     2       -33   -24
19 5     2     4        38    36
20 NA    2     NA       61   -39
```

I want to normalize variables `x`, `y`, and `z` on a 0-1 scale, and then produce some summary stats on them. I can produce the summary stats just fine using the code below

### Code that works:

```
library(tidyverse)

vars <- c('x', 'y', 'z')
names(vars) <- vars

summary_stats <- function(data){
       tibble(
           n = sum(!is.na(data)), 
           mean = round(mean(as.numeric(data), na.rm = T), digits = 3), 
           sd = round(sd(as.numeric(data), na.rm = T), digits = 3), 
           se = round(sd/sqrt(n), digits = 3) 
        ) 
}

table <- map_df(
    df %>% 
      dplyr::select(vars), 
    summary_stats, 
    .id = "covariate")

table

# A tibble: 3 × 5
  covariate     n  mean    sd    se
  <chr>     <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> 
1 x            16  4.75 1.88  0.47  
2 y            18  2.11 0.676 0.159  
3 z            17  3.35 1.41  0.342
```

### Code that doesn't work:

But i'm struggling to figure out how to normalize the variables. My latest attempt is to try this

```
summary_stats <- function(data){
 
  data_norm <- drop_na(data) %>% dplyr::summarize(
    (as.numeric(data) - min(as.numeric(data))) /
    (max(as.numeric(data)) - min(as.numeric(data)))
    )
       tibble(
           n = sum(!is.na(data_norm)), 
           mean = round(mean(as.numeric(data_norm), na.rm = T), digits = 3), 
           sd = round(sd(as.numeric(data_norm), na.rm = T), digits = 3), 
           se = round(sd/sqrt(n), digits = 3) 
        ) 
}

table <- map_df(
    df %>% 
      dplyr::select(vars), 
    summary_stats, 
    .id = "covariate")
```

### Errors:

But this returns the error

```
Error in UseMethod("drop_na_") : no applicable method for 'drop_na_' applied to an object of class "factor"
```

If I convert it to a numeric on the fly, so I have `data_norm <- drop_na(as.numeric(data))` etc., I then get a very similar error saying

```
Error in UseMethod("drop_na_") : no applicable method for 'drop_na_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

However, if I do this outside of the function it works fine

```
df %>% drop_na(x) %>% summarise(std_mean = (as.numeric(x) - min(as.numeric(x))) / (max(as.numeric(x)) - min(as.numeric(x))))

# A tibble: 16 × 1
   std_mean
      <dbl>
 1    0.857
 2    0.429
 3    0.714
 4    0.714
 5    0.143
 6    0.286
 7    0.571
....
```

I need to remove the NA values or when I try and normalize the returned variable will have all NAs if there is at least 1 NA in that column. And if I apply `drop_na()` outside the function (to the master tibble i feed in to the `map_dfr` function), it will drop any row that has at least 1 NA value in any variable from the df, rather than just the NA values from that column.

Can anyone help here?

### Update:

If I remove the `drop_na()` call from the function i get the following error

```
Error in UseMethod("summarise") : 
  no applicable method for 'summarise' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

This makes zero sense to me (i'm probably not understanding it) as summarise definitely works with numeric variables...

Comment: Try `as.numeric(as.character(data))`. This is probably a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Rui. I just tried running `data_norm <- drop_na(as.numeric(as.character(data))) %>% ...` but get the same error as before: `Error in UseMethod("drop_na_") : no applicable method for 'drop_na_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what's happening is that you're trying to write a function to take an entire data frame as an argument, but when you go to map it, you're actually only passing a single vector (e.g. `df$x`) as the argument to the function. This works fine for the first version of your function, but in the second version `drop_na` fails to work because it takes an [entire data frame for an argument](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.0/topics/drop_na). Same goes for `summarize`, which is why you were getting a similar error. It also works outside of your function because you're able to specify a single vector.

So, what I did was swap out `drop_na` for `na_omit`, and also reorganized your code a bit.

First, let's just define a separate `std_mean` function so we don't have to deal with `summarize`:

```
std_mean <- function(x){
  x <- na.omit(x)
  (as.numeric(x) - min(as.numeric(x)))/(max(as.numeric(x)) - min(as.numeric(x)))
}
```

Now we can go back and fix your original function:

```
summary_stats <- function(vec){
  
  data_norm <- std_mean(vec)
  n = length(data_norm)
  sd = round(sd(as.numeric(data_norm), na.rm = T), digits = 3)
  
  data.frame(
    n = n, 
    mean = round(mean(as.numeric(data_norm), na.rm = T), digits = 3), 
    sd = sd, 
    se = round(sd/sqrt(n), digits = 3) 
  ) 
}
```

We have to define `n` and `sd` beforehand because they were being used as arguments in other columns of the data frame. While it would be cool for `data.frame` to calculate the first column to then allow you to feed into later columns, that isn't the case.

And now we're ready to map:

```
map(df[vars],summary_stats)

$x
   n  mean    sd    se
1 16 0.536 0.269 0.067

$y
   n  mean    sd   se
1 18 0.556 0.338 0.08

$z
   n  mean    sd    se
1 17 0.588 0.353 0.086
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you NovaEthos! Really clear explanation, and it's helped me think more clearly about purrr functions. It actually did work for me without repeating the `n = ` and `sd = ` outside of the `data.frame()` command so i was able to simplify even further :)

Comment: @C.Robin of course!! yeah, ```purrr``` functions are a little tricky at first, but once you figure them out they're a game changer. for example, if you wanted all your results stacked on top of each other as rows, you can use ```map_dfr``` on your final step (the r stands for rows)